# adding meta data Dynamically for SEO

Tags: asp.net, seo, search-engine

I am adding dynamic meta Tags and meta description in multiple page at Page Load.**I need to know the way i am doing is good or not**? Shall i place meta data on pages statically? *I have approximately more than 1000 pages in project.*

Comment: Google bots can't ready dynamic data very well.

Comment: one of my page is loading on the basis of parameter. so i want to place meta on the basis of parameter? that is why i used dynamic. is there any alternative way.

Comment: Try to rewrite your URL from domain.com?s=param to domain.com/param/.

Comment: myUrl.com/index.aspx?shmQ=NPEVMFT0HPWFSONFOU

Comment: myUrl.com/index.aspx?shmQ=myseconPage

Comment: @MirShakeelHussain, Why do you insist on using such metadata for optimization? Do you think this is the best way? Nowadays, SEO is changed and those days gone  that meta description was silver bullet. In fact, such efforts are not so important and effective.